# GCP Terraform resource policy in compute module issues

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-build, terraform-provider-gcp, terragrunt

I am trying to add a `start-stop schedule` to our vm instances in our cloud repository **(it is a terraform/terragrunt setup)**

The example presented on the official site is this:

[image]

So since we use **Terragrunt** as a wrapper my module looks like this:

[image]

And for reference my **variable block** is this:

[image]

When i push the code it errors on step 0 in CloudBuild with the following error:

> Error: Reference to undeclared input variable on main.tf line 116, in resource "google_compute_resource_policy" "hourly": 116: time_zone = var.time_zone
> An input variable with the name "time_zone" has not been declared.       This variable can be declared with a variable "time_zone" {}block.

[image]

I have tried placing this variable in different positions of the block but i keep getting the same error. Has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Because the variable `instance_schedule_policy` is an object with different attributes, in order to reference the `time_zone` you need to do it like this: `var.instance_schedule_policy.time_zone`

Comment: I made the amendment:

```resource "google_compute_resource_policy" "hourly" {

  #description = "Start and stop instances"
  instance_schedule_policy {
  name   =  var.name
  region =  var.region
  #time_zone = var.time_zone
    vm_start_schedule {
    schedule = var.vm_start_schedule
    }
    vm_stop_schedule {
      schedule = var.vm_stop_schedule
    }
    
     time_zone = var.instance_schedule_policy.time_zone
    
  }
  }```

Comment: `on main.tf line 112, in resource "google_compute_resource_policy" "hourly":
 112:     schedule = var.vm_start_schedule

An input variable with the name "vm_start_schedule" has not been declared.
This variable can be declared with a variable "vm_start_schedule" {} block.`

Same for the stop_schedule. If i try and rename the schedule = var.vm_stop_schedule
to vm_stop_schedule = var.vm_stop_schedule

It errors advising it expects `schedule =`

Answer (score 0):

This is now resolved. I want to thank @kornshell93 for pointing me in the right direction.

I ended up using the block as suggested but creating a new module and hitting that from a separate section within my vm instance block. I linked to the project as a dependency this way. The previous method via the main compute instance module kept failing on all other vm instances, almost like it was expecting this block on all of them.

```
resource "google_compute_resource_policy" "hourly" {
name        = var.instance_schedule_policy.name
region      = var.region
project     = var.project
description = "Start and stop instances"

instance_schedule_policy {
  vm_start_schedule {
    schedule = var.instance_schedule_policy.vm_start_schedule
  }
  vm_stop_schedule {
    schedule = var.instance_schedule_policy.vm_stop_schedule
  }
  time_zone = var.instance_schedule_policy.time_zone
}
}
```

And the vm instance block

```
inputs = {
#instance start/stop schedules
project               = dependency.project.outputs.project_id
region                = "europe-west2"
instance_schedule_policy = {
name                      = "start-stop"
vm_start_schedule         = "30 07 * * *"
vm_stop_schedule          = "00 18 * * *"
time_zone                 = "GMT"
}
}
```